# A Definitive answer in one paragraph about Xcassets, full screen images and iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This question was answered a lot of times on StackOverflow but I think nobody answered this in an acceptable way.

I see a lot of people guessing, a lot of people that are wrong, a lot of hacking with creation of class extensions to solve that, but what I ask is direct answer.

Here it is:

I have this app for iOS 7, iPhone only, that is intended to work with all iPhones capable of running iOS 7 (iphone 4, iphone 5, iPhone 6 and 6+). So, we need 1x, 2x and 3x assets. Someone said in a question we don't need 1x because there is no iPhone capable of running iOS 7 with 1x. Wrong, we need 1x because we have the iPad 2, that can run iOS 7 and where the user may run our iPhone app or an iPad app for that matter.

when you choose device-specific asset on Images.xcassets and you select just the iPhone options, you are presented with 4 slots: `1x`, `2x`, `Retina 4 2x` and `3x`.

What sizes the images have to have to fill these slots?

**first guess**

- `1x` = 320 x 480
- `2x` = 640 x 960
- `Retina 4 2x` = 640 x 1136
- `3x` = 1242 x 2208

If this is correct, iPhone 6 will have to use `3x` image scaled down or `Retina 4 2x` images scaled up, as some say on SO. That later would be horrendous!!

**second guess**

- `1x` = 320 x 480
- `2x` = 750 x 1334
- `Retina 4 2x` = 640 x 1136
- `3x` = 1242 x 2208

This is be iPhone 4 having to scale up `1x`

**third guess**

- `1x` = 320 x 480
- `2x` = 640 x 960
- `Retina 4 2x` = 750 x 1334
- `3x` = 1242 x 2208

This is giving a bigger asset to Retina 4, hoping it will scale it down, what is better than scaling up.

My question is simple: which one is the correct one? I hope the third one is the correct.

Comment: Do you speak about launch screen or about some full-screen image resource? If about launch screen, why not to use `xib` instead?

Comment: Why are you guessing the sizes? Xcode shows you. For example, select the 2x square for the image asset. Look at the Attributes Inspector tab of the Utilities pane. The dimensions are shown right there.

Comment: @Azat iOS 7! No launch screen xibs!

Comment: @luk2302 as I understood, OP's question about stretching images on iPhone 6, and this device doesn't run iOS 7

Comment: I deem your assumption is incorrect for third case - "This is giving a bigger asset to Retina 4, hoping it will scale it down". If that is true, then logically you your statement "Someone said in a question we don't need 1x because there is no iPhone capable of running iOS 7 with 1x. Wrong, we need 1x because we have the iPad 2," is incorrect. You should be able to omit 1x images if system can scale down images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer in one paragraph that you want is to not use any if your guesses because i think the three is wrong.

you must use one image for each device model which dimension ( width x height) equal to the physical device width and height (i.e  750 x 1334 for iphone 6/6s) then at runtime you check the model of the device and according to the model you load the appropriate image. there is no need to the (@?x) images when you deal with edge to edge or fullscreen images.

Answer (score 1):

First Guess!

You can actually view the desired sizes in you asset file:

[image]
[image]

*Note*: iPhone portrait for iOS 7,8 is exactly the same!

Comment: Unfortunately this expected size line doesn't show on Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: You need to view the `Attribute Inspector` to see this information (the third tab in the right Xcode windows (Utilities))

Comment: How would Xcode know what size YOUR image should have, you need to provide it.

Comment: @luk2302 - I disagree with that. Xcode has the obligation to know where the image is being used and calculate the expected sizes based on the point size they have on interface builder. The problem is that Xcode is half cooked in all possible fronts. This xcassets is an example, not allowing localization. Badly implemented.

Comment: I agree that Xcode should maybe calculate the sizes for the other image Sizes if you provide at least one image e.g. for @2x. Unfortunately that does apparently not work :/

Comment: @SpaceDog did you intentionally remove the acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

> What sizes the images have to have to fill these slots?

Apple has already answered it. See [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html). The document was cited in quite a few questions on Stack Overflow.

To keep this out of "link on answer" territory, here's part of the table Apple provides:

[image]

---

> My question is simple: which one is the correct one?

You should reference the Apple document and stop guessing. The Apple document tells you what to use. There's no need to guess.

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I was trying to get as an answer. This Apple documentation, does not answers a lot of things and creates more doubts. 3rd and 4th columns, for example, is telling me that @2x is both 640x960 and 640x1136. This doc don't answer how do I fill those slots. I have only one 2x and I want to cover all iphones.

Comment: @SpaceDog - I cited the exact questions you asked. If you have a different question in mind, then you need to ask it :)